# How can I resolve a persistent Unity (actually Gradle) minsdk error in manifest

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I have removed all elements from all AndroidManifest.xml files in my project tree and added to my main manifest at /Assest/Plugins/AndroidManifest.xml the following lines:

```
<meta-data android:name="uses-sdk" tools:node="remove" />
<meta-data android:name="minSdkVersion" tools:node="remove" />
```

I see logs in the output as follows:

```
/Users/mark/dev/unity/MyProject/Temp/gradleOut/unityLibrary/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:4:3-60 Warning: meta-data#uses-sdk was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:4 to remove other declarations but no other declaration present
```

Yet I still get the following - "GRADLE ERROR : minsdk-in-manifest"
and find the following in my merged manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
```

Comment: I was facing this issue too. If you have added an external package to your project then go and search in the scripts. Some scripts are generating the manifest files. Just search in your project "uses-sdk" if you find it just remove line.Probably in will be in editor scripts

Comment: Fixed - turns out that after removing the uses-sdk node from the manifest. One must quit and restart unity. :/

Comment: I think it would be enough to delete the `Temp` folder